# Deserializing xml string to an object and I get empty list of missing list element. Why does it not return null?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, deserialization

```
public class Warning
{

    public Warning()
    {

    }

    public Warning(String name, List<String> conflictList)
    {
        Name = name;
        ConflictList = conflictList;
    }

    public string Name 
    { 
        get; 
        set; 
    }

    public List<String> ConflictList
    {
        get;
        set; 
    }

    public static Warning ReadXML(string xml)
    {
        Warning warning = null;

        try
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Warning));
            using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(xml))
            {
                XmlTextReader xtr = new XmlTextReader(sr);
                warning = (Warning)serializer.Deserialize(xtr);
                xtr.Close();
                sr.Close();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }

        return warning;
    }

    public void Save(string filename)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Warning));
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, this);
            writer.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

If I deserializing the following xml string and I get non-null values back for both Name and ConflictList. This is fine and what I expect.

```
Warning w1 = Warning.ReadXML(
    "<Warning><Name>test warning</Name><ConflictList><string>file1.txt</string></ConflictList></Warning>");
```

w1.Name returns "test warning" and w1.ConflictList returns a list containing the text "file1.txt"

However, if I deserialize the following xml string, w2.Name returns null, which i understand, but ConflictList is actually a list with a Count of 0. I expected it to be null as well. How come?

```
Warning w2 = Warning.ReadXML("<Warning></Warning>");
```

I am sure in some cases w1.ConflictList can return null if the element is not present in the xml string, but when does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

I too would have expected it to leave it alone if it isn't in the xml, but I too can reproduce  what you are saying, both "as is", and with `[XmlElement(...)]` on the member. I guess *internally* it is newing up the list "in case".

I also tried the alternative syntax just using a `get` and a lazy initializer, i.e.

```
// note: doesn't work; see answer text
private List<string> conflictList;
public List<String> ConflictList
{
    get { return conflictList ?? (conflictList = new List<string>()); }
}
```

but it still invokes this getter, even when no conflict data is included. And annoyingly the `*Specified` pattern only ever gets called for data that *is* specified - it doesn't get called for data that *isn't* specified, else you could do:

```
// note: doesn't work; see answer text
[XmlIgnore]
public bool ConflictListSpecified
{
    get { return ConflictList != null; }
    set { if (!value) ConflictList = null; }
}
```

Add to that the fact that serialization callbacks aren't supported in `XmlSerializer` and I'm out of options.

I've tested it back to .NET 2.0, and it behaves the same there too...